# Filter Array of Objects using RegExp? in Angular 5-9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How should I filter objects using RegExp (including title, email & name)

**title** & **name** should be in alphabets only.
**Email** should be valid

RegExp Patterns:

**Email =** /[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}/

**Title & Name =** /^[A-Za-z]+$/

if any one email is invalid, that invalid email should be stored in different variable & other objects should be stored in different variable.

inside JSON, first object email is invalid, so I want to store this object in other variable

```
items = [
{
    title: "This is title", 
    email: "testtest.com",
    status: "confirmed"
},
{
    title: "This another one", 
    email: "someone@something.com",
    status: "pending"
{    
    title: "Just a random string", 
    email: "me@you.co.uk",
    status: "pending"
{    
]
```

Comment: hey, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please test this approach

```js
var items = [
{
    title: "This is title", 
    email: "testtest.com",
    status: "confirmed"
},
{
    title: "This another one", 
    email: "someone@something.com",
    status: "pending"
},
{    
    title: "Just a random string", 
    email: "me@you.co.uk",
    status: "pending"
}    
]

var filtered_not_matching = items.filter(s => !/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}/.test(s.email))

console.log(filtered_not_matching)
```

The `.test()` API runs a search for a match between a RegExp and a String.

Please find the following article on regex matching in javascript, you can find several APIs regarding regex matching

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/understanding-regular-expression-matching-with-test-match-exec-search-and-split

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to filter out to filter out emails that are invalid based on the regex rule, you can use `Array.filter()` on the `items` array, and filter out any objects whose `email` does not match the regex. You can use [text or match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for your regex matching.

This is how you can do it:

```js
const items = [{
    title: "This is title",
    email: "testtest.com",
    status: "confirmed"
  },
  {
    title: "This another one",
    email: "someone@something.com",
    status: "pending"
  },
  {
    title: "Just a random string",
    email: "me@you.co.uk",
    status: "pending"
  }
];

const emailRegex = new RegExp(/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}/)
const titleRegex = new RegExp('/^[A-Za-z]+$/');

const res = items.filter(({
  title,
  email
}) => !email.match(emailRegex));
console.log(res)

const res2 = items.filter(({
  title,
  email
}) => !emailRegex.test(email));
console.log(res2)
```